# How can I intergrate my django app to an alredy made database, probably from a PHP app

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

this is part of the database. The extention is .sql

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.2.0.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: May 20, 2011 at 05:08 PM
-- Server version: 5.1.36
-- PHP Version: 5.2.9-2

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `bincomphptest`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `agentname`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `agentname`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `agentname` (
  `name_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` char(13) NOT NULL,
  `pollingunit_uniqueid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

I was creating a new database on django with mysqlite but I think I'm inexperience and this maybe possible

Comment: It's definitely possible to access an existing database with existing tables in your Django app.  Have you looked through the standard Django documentation to try to figure this out?  I haven't done Django programming in years, but I assume that how to access tables without creating them must be outlined therein.  Maybe this would be helpful: https://djangoadventures.com/how-to-integrate-django-with-existing-database/#:~:text=In%20order%20to%20use%20an,to%20solve%20this%20exact%20problem.

Comment: What language created the database is irrelevant. Just research how to connect to mysql from django.

Answer (score 1):

Django can read legacy databases and even auto-generate the models for them,

connect to the db from settings and then run this command from your terminal

```py
python manage.py inspectdb
```

it will print the models and you can use it as normal Django models

Answer (score 0):

To interpret these values in django you must look carefully at each field type so that you can create the variables that will store these values, such as `name_id`, `firstname`, `lastname`...

```
# settings.py 
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'django',
        'USER' : 'userid',
        'PASSWORD' :'password',
        'HOST' : 'localhost'
    }
}
```

this example should work once the **table** has been defined in `models` and that you have added the respective app `'exampleApp.apps...'` in `settings.py`.

```py
import uuid
from django.db import models

class Agent(models.Model): 
    name_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email  = models.EmailField(max_length=255)
    phone  = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```